Spatie Browsershot only working with older version of Puppeteer
Today I had issue getting Browsershot to work.
It would always timeout.
So I thought I was running some bad combination of versions of PHP/Laravel/Node/Puppeteer.
So I made a clean Laravel project with everything at its latest version:
PHP: 8.3.2  
Laravel: 11.1.4
Node: 20.11.1
Puppeteer: 22.13.0

Then I ran a simple code:
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->save('example.pdf');

But again, I get a timeout error (30 seconds), but no explanation what caused that.
So again, I installed an older Puppeteer version - 20.7.4, and Browsershot started working.
The problem is - the cause is unknown, and also I get a warning that older Puppeteer versions are not supported and have security issues.
